# How Did Keras Determine The Number of Parameters In My Model

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I have the following keras model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = keras.Sequential()
layer_in = keras.Input(shape=(256))
layer1 = layers.Dense(2, activation="relu", name="layer1")
layer2 = layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer2")
layer3 = layers.Dense(4, name="layer3")
model.add(layer_in)
model.add(layer1)
model.add(layer2)
model.add(layer3)
model.build()
```

Which produces the following  when `keras.summary()` is called

```
Model: "sequential_8"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 layer1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 514       
                                                                 
 layer2 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 9         
                                                                 
 layer3 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 16        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 539
Trainable params: 539
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

How did  Keras determine the layers should have 514, 9, and 16 parameters respectively?

I would have thought that the first layer would have 256 parameters since the input layer, `layer_in`, was instantiated with `shape=(256)`

Answer (score 1):

As you are using dense layers, Keras determine the params in models as following calculations :

```
# of params = # of outputs * (# of inputs + 1)
```

Hence, the calculations is as follows :

```
Number of params layer 1 = 2 * (256+1) = 2*257 = 514 Params

Number of params layer 2 = 3 * (2+1) = 3*3 = 9 Params

Number of params layer 3 = 4 * (3+1) = 4*4 = 16 Params
```

Comment: Is this mentioned somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: This is fully connected layer. Its a generic rule apply to every fully connected network no matter ghe library